# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest breaks when accessed from alternate domain name

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have two domain names that point to my website, nathannifong.com, and uncc.ath.cx.
Javascript on the site occasionally needs to pull down resources with XMLHttpRequest. All URLs of resources in client scripts refer to nathannifong.com, and when a user comes to the site by uncc.ath.cx, the scripts fail because of cross domain secuity policy in JavaScript.

What should I change so that users can come to the site by any domain name, but the XMLHttpRequests still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Domain Name in the URL's to make a ajax request, remove it hence the domain is automatically mapped to the one the user is using and you will not have the cross domain issues.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nathannifong.com/LayerCake/simdata/rec1_i0.csv. Origin http://uncc.ath.cx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  The request was for "simdata/rec1_i0.csv" What's going on?

Comment: Change the request URL from nathannifong.com/LayerCake/simdata/rec1_i0.csv to load /LayerCake/simdata/rec1_i0.csv, it will work.

Comment: I did, and got this error anyways. Are there any other reasons this could happen?

Comment: Nevermind, it works, I had a little typo screwing things up. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Oh God, please, pleeeeease, if you fix the bug, let us know how you did it. I was so close...

Answer (score 1):

xhr is contrained by [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and will not work cross domain - for that use jsonp as already mentioned.

Comment: correct me if i'm mistaken, but he's describing a situation in which there are two domain names for the same host... this doesn't violate the SOP, because it's still the same host, port, and protocol. just a different domain name.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JSONToJSONP.aspx), JSONP would be a way of accomplishing this. I've not used it myself, however, but it might be worth taking a look there.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at `window.location` to determine the page's domain, and then use that to load the request? That way you'd be sure that the request was going to the right domain. You could also look into JSONP, but only for GET requests.